# Java: Recursive function not generating power set of a set

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to generate a power set (all possible subsets) of integers based on a given set of integers. I am trying to use recursion based on the principle that each element in the master set can be in a subset or not in a subset. However, when I run my function on the example set `{1, 5, 11, 5}`, I am missing subsets, such as `{1, 5, 5}`. Below is my Java code:

```
// Function to generate power set of given set S
public static void determinePowerSet(int[] baseSet, List<Integer> currSet, int index, int sum)
{
    // If the current index is at the end, we've finished generating subsets
    if (index == baseSet.length) {
        return;
    }
    
    // The subset in which we add the current element in the list
    List<Integer> addToSet = new LinkedList<Integer>(currSet);
    addToSet.add(baseSet[index]);
    
    // Do not add the current element to the set
    determinePowerSet(baseSet, currSet, index + 1, sum);
    // Add the current element to the set
    determinePowerSet(baseSet, addToSet, index + 1, sum + baseSet[index]);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    determinePowerSet(new int[] {1, 5, 11, 5}, new LinkedList<Integer>(), 0, 0);
}
```

Below is the output of the function call:

```
sum = 0, currSet = [], index = 0
sum = 0, currSet = [], index = 1
sum = 0, currSet = [], index = 2
sum = 0, currSet = [], index = 3
sum = 11, currSet = [11], index = 3
sum = 5, currSet = [5], index = 2
sum = 5, currSet = [5], index = 3
sum = 16, currSet = [5, 11], index = 3
sum = 1, currSet = [1], index = 1
sum = 1, currSet = [1], index = 2
sum = 1, currSet = [1], index = 3
sum = 12, currSet = [1, 11], index = 3
sum = 6, currSet = [1, 5], index = 2
sum = 6, currSet = [1, 5], index = 3
sum = 17, currSet = [1, 5, 11], index = 3
```

Comment: I have executed your code, it worked properly, generating all 16 combinations.

Comment: what's the pupose of `sum`? it's value is never read

Comment: @YashShah Did you use the same function call as I did in the answer? Below is the output of my function.

Comment: Try printing currSet in if (index == baseSet.length)

Comment: What about debugging? Or try to execute the program with pen and paper for a small failing example and ompare it with what the computer does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything is fine in your code. Let's take a look:

```
class Solution{

// Function to generate power set of given set S
    public static void determinePowerSet(int[] baseSet, List<Integer> currSet, int index, int sum)
    {
        // If the current index is at the end, we've finished generating subsets
        if (index == baseSet.length) {
            for(int i : currSet)
                System.out.print(i+" ");
            System.out.println();
            return;
        }

        // The subset in which we add the current element in the list
        List<Integer> addToSet = new LinkedList<Integer>(currSet);
        addToSet.add(baseSet[index]);

        // Do not add the current element to the set
        determinePowerSet(baseSet, currSet, index + 1, sum);
        // Add the current element to the set
        determinePowerSet(baseSet, addToSet, index + 1, sum + baseSet[index]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        determinePowerSet(new int[] {1, 5, 11, 5}, new LinkedList<Integer>(), 0, 0);
    }
    
}
```

***OUTPUT:***

```
5 
11 
11 5 
5 
5 5 
5 11 
5 11 5 
1 
1 5 
1 11 
1 11 5 
1 5 
1 5 5 
1 5 11 
1 5 11 5
```